# RoR 5.1.4 Sprockets es6.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6, erb, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Have a Ruby on Rails 5.1.4 project with a single model. The application does not compile my app/assets/javascripts/posts.**es6**.erb file.

The idea is to pass a Ruby value to a ES6 Javascript bridging it with ERB like so: console.log('<%= Rails.env %>').

When changing my file to app/assets/javascripts/posts.**js**.erb it works fine but the es6 extension fails.

Rails just seems to silently ignore my es6.erb file.

Can anyone help?

Comment: what version of uglifier are you using?

Comment: the project is using version 4.0.2

Comment: is it for production environment?

Comment: No. I am just running the project in dev evn. It's a dummy project in which I scaffolded a single model to play with es6 and the asset pipeline.

Comment: show how you are including your file. via render partial? it must be interpreted.

Comment: @adcosta thanks for taking the time with this. Basically I am simple letting loading the tree with **//= require_tree .** in app/assets/javascripts/application.js When changing my file like so app/assets/javascripts/posts.js.erb it works fine but the es6 extension fails.

Comment: hi @slombo did you find a solution?